# Explanation for some simple code

Tags: html, string, salt

I'm trying to understand a little piece of code. Can someone explain what exactly is going on with it. Is it shifting the string on even pieces to the right?

```
salt = '40cf738d702c78d8939da5e8cfd324ae';
str_overral = salt;
str_overral = str_overral.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gi, '').toLowerCase();
str_res='';
for (i=0; i<str_overral.length; i++) {
    l=str_overral.substr(i,1);
    d=l.charCodeAt(0);
     if ( Math.floor(d/2) == d/2 ) {
       str_res+=l;
    } else {
       str_res=l+str_res;
    }
}
```

Comment: Poor quality code... anyway. It filters the string to keep only lowercase letters and numbers, then is puts half the letters (ACEGI...) to the left and the other half (BDFHJ...) to the right...

Answer (score 1):

the new string if built with even characters to the end/right (and I mean the character's code) while odd characters go to the beginning/left

```js
salt = '40cf738d702c78d8939da5e8cfd324ae';
str_overral = salt;
str_overral = str_overral.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gi, '').toLowerCase();
str_res='';
for (i=0; i<str_overral.length; i++) {
    l=str_overral.substr(i,1);
    d=l.charCodeAt(0);
    console.log('str['+i+']: "' + l + '" ('+d+')');
     if ( Math.floor(d/2) == d/2 ) {
       console.log('even, pushing to the end/right/back');
       str_res+=l;
    } else {
       console.log('odd, pushing to the beginning/left/front');
       str_res=l+str_res;
    }
    console.log('res: "' + str_res + '"');
}
```